# how to set the first author together?

Tags: author

I want to set author1 and author2 as the common first author. I use:

```
\author{author1\inst{1} \footnotemark[1]\and author2\inst{1}\footnotemark[1] \and author3\inst{2}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{The author contribute  equally to this paper.}
```

But it cause the following problem:

```
Use of \@xfootnotenext doesn't match its definition. \maketitle
```

Does someone know how to solve it?

Comment: What you want to really achieve? I mean, is your problem to write multiple authors in your title or to use a common footnote for all the authors? They are two different questions with two different answers. Of course, they can be combined but I want to understand which is your question.

Comment: @gvgramazio From the footnote contents it looks like OP needs a common footnote for two (or more) authors. A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be nice, as a quick mockup gives no errors for me with a dumme declaration for \inst

Comment: Also, I don't understand why he use both `\inst` and `\footnotemark`. It looks like he/she wants to both set a footnote for institution and for saying that they contributed equally to the paper.

Comment: Which isn't surprising in scientific publishing. In a number of countries at least, a certain number of publications is required (with you as first author) before you can get your PhD. And sharing a publication (as here) is accepted.

Comment: @remco, No, I don't mean that is uncommon to share a publication. I mean that I don't like the result of having multiple footnote mark one after the other if they could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Until the question will be more precise, this is my solutions.

### First solution (using multiple authors and redefine title page)

Now each author has is command (you can easily expand to a lot of authors). All the authors have the same footnotemark and footnotetext.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\firstauthor#1{\gdef\@firstauthor{#1}}
\def\secondauthor#1{\gdef\@secondauthor{#1}}
\def\thirdauthor#1{\gdef\@thirdauthor{#1}}
\makeatother

\firstauthor{John Doe}
\secondauthor{Jack Smith}
\thirdauthor{Jack Doe}
\title{My Awesome Title}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@firstauthor\footnote{The authors contribute equally to this paper.}
        \and
        \@secondauthor\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]
        \and
        \@thirdauthor
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
\end{titlepage}%
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

#### Note on the usage with `hyperref`

All works fine, except a warning in the compilation and the fact that the footnotemark link on the second author is broken (that is the reason of the warning).

### Second solution

I used the authblk package. Since I don't know which is the visual result that you would like, take a look at the [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf) if you want to change the visual result. I modified the title-page only to insert the footnote without mark.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[affil-it,blocks]{authblk}


\title{My Awesome Title}

\author{John Doe\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{First University}

\author{Jack Smith\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Second University}

\author{Jack Doe\thanks{jack.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Third University}

\date{\today}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \blfootnote{John Doe and Jack Smith equally contribute to this paper.}
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
\end{titlepage}%
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: example_2]

If the first and second authors have exactly the same institution (department, institution and/or whatever) you could substitute

```
\author{John Doe\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Some department, First Institution}
\author{Jack Smith\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Some department, Second Institution}
\author{Jack Doe\thanks{jack.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Some Department, Third Institution}
```

with

```
\author{John Doe\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\author{Jack Smith\thanks{john.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Some department, First Institution}
\author{Jack Doe\thanks{jack.doe@uni.com}}
\affil{Some department, Second Institution}
```

and authblk will automatically handle resulting in

[image: example_3]

Comment: Given the contents of the footnote text in the question, I'd expect at least one author that should not get the footnote (e.g. 2 PhD students can have publications where both students need to be "1st author", but not thier supervisor, who would also be a co-author)

Comment: @remco You're right, but I don't know if one of them is a supervisor, an author or whatever. Anyway I've added the case with no footnote mark for the third author.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to add a footnote to state the author1 and author2 contribute equally. \inst represents the institution. And I have post my solution below the question. Your solution is also useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\author{
     First Author\thanks{Same Institute} \and 
     Second Author\footnotemark[1]  \and 
     Third author \thanks{UVW} 
}
```

\footnotemark[1] indicating the shared footnote.

Answer (score -1):

```
\author{author1\inst{1, 2\star} \and author2\inst{2\star} \and authour3\inst{2}}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{The two authors contributed  equally to this paper.}
```

This is the result.
[image]

Comment: Is this an answer to the question you asked? Or a clarification?

Comment: I suggest you to separate each author and don't put them all in the same author variable. Also, if you don't change again the symbol all the following footnotes will be marked with symbols.

Comment: Yes. I tried your method, but all the authors can not be shown, maybe because of the template? The template only put them all in a author variable.  And my method make all the footnote mark with symblos.

Comment: @F.Mei I need more clarification. Are you using a template that you cannot modify? Are you using a lot of packages that conflicts with the ones I used? If it's something like that you should add more infos in your question.

Comment: @F.Mei anyway look at the second solution that I propose in my answer. I think it work good in your case. IF you already use a template for your title page, edit your answer and post it so I can see it.

Comment: @F.Mei if this answer is only to add a clarification you should edit your question and not adding an answer. Please delete this answer after you read my comments.